# Why was Guts called the Black Swordsman?

Tags: berserk

> In the [Berserk](http://berserk.wikia.com/) manga, after the carnage at Eclipse, the protagonist [Guts](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Guts) repeatedly came to be called as the Black Swordsman by everyone, other than his new friends-cum-comrades. I've read the manga but I couldn't figure out the possible reason for it.

However, I do have some following clues but cannot account them as the primary reason for such.

> 1. In the first and the last episode (scene before the ending) of the [Berserk anime](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Berserk_%28Anime%29), Guts skin color was neither white nor dark (like of [Casca](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Casca)) but something different.
>
>  2. The color of Guts's outfit excluding the armor was almost black. After the addition of [Berserker Armor](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker_Armor), everything he wore was black.

As you can see, these reasons are not very convincing. Therefore, I ask the question again:

**Why was Guts called the Black Swordsman?**

**Note**: No racial discrimination or apartheid is intended in **1.**

Answer (score 3):

Guts was known as the "*Swordsman clad in black*", which was eventually shortened to "*Black Swordsman*".

[image]
*Guts before he got his Berserk Armor.*

[image]
*Guts with his Berserk Armor.*

His armor was always black, but the most relevant item was his black cape, which always covered his whole body in black when he wasn't fighting.

Comment: `Guts was known as the "Swordsman clad in black"` -- I don't remember this in manga. Can you confirm the source?

Comment: @Firelord. I'll see what I can find. So far, I haven't had any luck finding a source for my claim. I do remember him being called that once, although it might've been an inofficial fan translation.